# Date formatting using python

Tags: python, datetime

To get date I use this block:

```
currentDate = date.today()
today = currentDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

It returns me this format 12/22/2014 or 01/02/2015
Then I have to compare to string from the file (note: I can't change the string) 12/22/2014 or 1/2/2015 and I use:

```
if l[0] == today:
```

In second case it obviously failed.
My question: how could I change strftime() in order to return only one charachter for month and day when it has preceeding zero?

Comment: compare two datetime objects not strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), it doesn't appear that there is a character sequence for this. However, you could correct the result as follows:

```
today = currentDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').replace("/0", "/")
if today[0] == '0':
    today = today[1:]
```

This will eliminate any leading `0`s so long as the values are split with a forward slash.

Comment: That would not replace the first leading `0`

Comment: -OMGthchy, I like you suggestion, I did this:
(Pdb) today = currentDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').replace("/0", "/")
(Pdb) p today
'01/3/2015'
Hence it replaced second zero, is it option to remove both zeros?

Comment: @susik there was a typo where I checked it against 0 not '0', this should work now

Comment: Great!! Works perfect now both when date has or does not have zero in date. Appreciate it.

Comment: @susik no problem. Now if you don't understand the code I advise you read through it until you do, as things like this come up a lot.

Answer (score 2):

just compare datetime objects:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

currentDate = date.today()
file_dt = "1/3/2015"
dt2 = datetime.strptime(file_dt,"%m/%d/%Y")
print(dt2.date() == currentDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
today = currentDate.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')
```

WARNING, not standard, so could not work on some platforms (check strftime(3) documentation, section "Glibc notes"). Anyway, I agree with other answers, better to compare datetime objects